# Serverview Raid Manager does not show GUI

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2012, serverview

I am relatively new to servers and recently bought an Fujitsu Primergy TX 150 S7. I installed Windows Server 2012 on a temporary HDD as I could not figure out how to set up the included Raid Controller with 2 SAS HDDs.

I tried using the tool of Fujitsu "Serverview Raid Manager" and worked around the certificate problem. But when I try to open the website `localhost:3173` it just shows one line:

`permissions="sandbox">`

How can I fix this?

Comment: How did you "work around the certificate problem"?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I edited the amDPatch.ini to allow HTTP

Answer (score -1):

Install Java exp. java 8 upd. 151

Comment: You would need to explain a lot better how this is supposed to help.